# Amazon Web Services - Deploy Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, maven, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a spring boot application that I am deploying onto EB (Elastic Beanstalk) AWS. The app works fine locally, however, I get a 404 on all pages I try to access on the deployed version. Also, I can't access any of the static content under the static folder either. All REST endpoints work fine.

My project structure is as follows

```
-- src
  -- main
     -- kotlin
     -- resources
        -- static
           -- css
           -- fonts
           -- images
           -- js
        -- templates (contains html files)
```

I've tried defining option_settings in a .config file under a .ebextensions folder

```
option_settings
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:java:staticfiles: 
    /public/: WEB-INF/classes/static
    /static/: WEB-INF/classes/staticenter code here
```

I've also tried adding the following to my spring configuration class

```
@Configuration open class MvcConfig : WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

override fun addViewControllers(registry: ViewControllerRegistry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("homepage")
    registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("homepage")
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("homepage")
    registry.addViewController("/homepage").setViewName("homepage")
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login")
    registry.addViewController("/products").setViewName("productsList")
    registry.addViewController("/productdetail").setViewName("productDetail")
}

@Bean
open fun viewResolver(): ViewResolver {
    val bean = InternalResourceViewResolver()

    bean.setPrefix("/templates/")
    bean.setSuffix(".html")

    return bean
}

override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry?) {
    // Register resource handler for all static folders
    registry!!.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/statics/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic())
}

@Bean
open fun errorPageFilter(): ErrorPageFilter {
    return ErrorPageFilter()
}

@Bean
open fun disableSpringBootErrorFilter(filter: ErrorPageFilter): FilterRegistrationBean {
    val filterRegistrationBean = FilterRegistrationBean()
    filterRegistrationBean.filter = filter
    filterRegistrationBean.isEnabled = false
    return filterRegistrationBean
}
```

I am deploying onto tomcat8 that sits behind an Apache proxy server.

My EB settings are correct as I tried to deploy a simpler application onto the instance, which worked fine.

Please let me know if there are any further details I need to provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the resourceHandler, the classpath it self was never added to the resource handler, even though servlet logging was indicating it was.

Spring by default maps the following paths

```
classpath:META-INF/resources/
classpath:resources/
classpath:static/
classpath:public/
```

needed to add the /** to the mapping. The solution was to modify the code to the following

```
override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry?) {
    registry!!.addResourceHandler("/**", "/static/**")
              .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/", "classpath:/static/").setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2,TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic())
}

@Bean
open fun viewResolver(): ViewResolver {
    val bean = InternalResourceViewResolver()
    bean.setSuffix(".html")
    return bean
}
```